# gcloud identity token vs access token

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-authentication

What is the difference between access-token and identity-token when we use `gcloud auth print-access-token` and `gcloud auth print-identity-token`?

What are the cases where we can use one and not the other in Google Cloud context.

Why we have `print-access-token` for `gcloud auth` and `gcloud auth application-default` while we have `print-identity-token` only for `gcloud auth`

Comment: This is a good question, but I could write a small book to answer it. The first step is for you to read about OAuth and OIDC tokens. There are three (Access, Identity, and Refresh). Then review the authorization token that a Google Cloud Service requires (Access or Identity) varies by service and access method. The CLI documentation covers the differences between **gcloud auth** and **gcloud auth application-default**.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Definition and and in Google Context :**

[Access tokens](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/access-tokens) (which aren't always JWTs) are used to inform an API that the bearer of the token has been authorized to access the API and perform a predetermined set of actions (specified by the scopes granted).

- Access tokens must never be used for authentication. Access tokens
  cannot tell if the user has authenticated.
- In Google Context, an OAuth 2.0 access token is useful for
  authenticating access from a service account to Google Cloud APIs.

[ID tokens](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/id-tokens) are used in token-based authentication. These tokens are signed JSON Web Tokens JWT used to assert identity and do not necessarily carry any implicit authorization against a resource. These tokens will just declare who the caller is and any service that the token is sent to can verify the token's integrity by verifying the signature payload provided with the JWT. The application receives an ID token after a user successfully authenticates, then consumes the ID token and extracts user information from it, which it can then use to personalize the user's experience.

1. The aud: field describes the service name this token was created to
   invoke. If a service receives an id_token, it must verify its
   integrity (signature), validity (is it expired) and if the aud: field
   is the predefined name it expects to see. If the names do not match,
   the service should reject the token as it could be a replay intended
   for another system.
2. In Google Context, an OIDC ID token is useful for authenticating the
   identity of a service account to services that accept OpenID Connect.

**Consider the following example use case for**

1. Access token :

To get elevated permissions on a project, a service administrator can impersonate a service account to call Google Cloud APIs by creating an OAuth 2.0 access token belonging to that service account. The token has a short lifetime so that the elevated permissions are temporary. Using short-lived tokens helps you implement the principle of least privilege across your identities and resources. It can also be useful when there is an emergency in a production environment, and a service administrator needs a short-term elevated authorization for debugging.

2. ID Token :

By creating an OIDC ID token belonging to a service account, a service running on Google Cloud can authenticate itself to another service deployed on a third-party cloud provider, such as a data pipeline job. If the target service is configured with OIDC, the authentication will succeed.

**Coming on to the gcloud CLI commands :**

- gcloud credentials and application default credentials are managed
  separately.
- If you activated a service account key file this only can be used for
  gcloud commands but not for application default credentials.
- gcloud auth application-default set of commands are there only to
  manage application default and having nothing to do with commands in
  gcloud auth

> 1. gcloud auth application-default print-access-token

- This obtains your credentials via a web flow and stores them in 'the
  well-known location for Application Default Credentials'.'The
  well-known location for Application Default Credentials' is a file
  named application_default_credentials.json located in your local
  ~/.config/gcloud/ directory. Now any code/SDK you run will be able to
  find the credentials automatically. This is a good stand-in when you
  want to locally test code which would normally run on a server and
  use a server-side credentials file. In these cases gcloud auth
  application-default print-access-token works as it authenticates with
  a user identity (via a web flow) but using the credentials as a proxy
  for a service account.

> 2. gcloud auth print-access-token

- Displays the current service account's access token.

> 3. gcloud auth print-identity-token

- Print an identity token for the specified account. If not specified,
  the current active account will be used.
- Both Google Service Accounts and Users can get id_tokens but with an
  important distinction: User login oauth flows issue id_tokens
  statically bound to the web or oauth2 client_id the flow as
  associated with. That is, if a user logs into a web application
  involving oauth2, the id_token that the provider issues to the
  browser will have the aud: field bound to the oauth2 client_id.
  Service Accounts on the other hand, can participate in a flow where
  it can receive an id_token from google with an aud: field specified
  earlier.
- You can print identitytoken using gcloud command for service
  accounts, impersonated service accounts and compute engine instances.

Comment: 1/2) I like your answer. Here are a few tidbits. 1) Google Access Tokens are a hash of a token stored in GCP. This is primarily for fast lookups as these tokens are used almost everywhere. 2) Access Tokens are also the result of Authentication but do not provide the authorized identity (usually). Azure is an exception that includes extensive identity and location information. 3) ID Tokens are used for Identity-Based Authorization (you stated token-based authentication).

Comment: 2/2) 4) You wrote **gcloud credentials and application default credentials are managed separately.**. I think you meant **Google Cloud credentials instead of gcloud credentials.** I think you are blurring the line between credentials and the applications that use/generate them. 5) This is not correct **If you activated a service account key file this only can be used for gcloud commands but not for application default credentials.**.

Comment: Ignore my point 4. I think I misunderstood your choice of words. The term **gcloud** is used for too many items.

Comment: Thank you very much @Priyashree for taking the time to write a thorough answer. Also thank you John for your comments ! You rock  People !